# How to setup different price,visibility and inventory of product according multiple store?

Tags: magento, visible, inventory, price

I have to store 1 - Ahmadabad and 2 - Surat
i have one category named online shopping 
in that i have one product named shop
this product price in Ahmadabad is 20 rs.But 25 rs. in Surat.also it's stock of shop in Ahmadabad is 30 and in Surat is only 25.So how can i manage this in my different store.

In short how to manage product price,visibility and inventory from different store at same time?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple stores, Magento provides an option to change the store in product edit page. You can change the values of product attribute based on the stotes.